# Bridge Scoring Question

Tags: scoring

Rubber Bridge:  Declarer is vulnerable.  The bid is 3 clubs.  Declarer only makes 5 tricks for down 4.  What is the penalty?

Comment: I already knew the answer, however a bridge buddy is insistent that unmade tricks towards book do not count towards a penalty, only those odd tricks above book are considered for penalties.

Answer (score 0):

Four tricks down vulnerable not doubled is 100 points per trick, 400 points total for the opposing team. Nobody scores below the line, opponents do get 400 points above the line.

More information [here](http://www.acbl.org/learn_page/how-to-play-bridge/how-to-keep-score/rubber-bridge/).